# How set an Builder object from constructor

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, lombok, google-cloud-bigtable

I want to replace existing (empty builder) object with newer one using constructor.
My code looks like this

```
public class BigtableChannelPrimer implements ChannelPrimer {
    private List<String> appName;
    @Bean
    private EnhancedBigtableStubSettings settingsTemplate(){
        return EnhancedBigtableStubSettings.newBuilder().build();
    }
    @Bean
    @RefreshScope
    BigtableChannelPrimer create() {
        EnhancedBigtableStubSettings.Builder builder =
            EnhancedBigtableStubSettings.newBuilder()
                .setProjectId(projectId)
               .build());

        // Disable retries for priming request
        builder
            .readRowSettings()
            .setRetrySettings(
                builder
                    .readRowSettings()
                    .getRetrySettings()
                    .toBuilder()
                    .setMaxAttempts(1)                  
                    .build());
        return new BigtableChannelPrimer(builder.build(), tableIds);
    }
public BigtableChannelPrimer(
        EnhancedBigtableStubSettings settingsTemplate,
        List<String> appName) {
        this.settingsTemplate(). ======================= 
        this.appName= appName;
    }
}
```

In this constructor how can set `this.settingsTemplate().` something like this.

I also have other methods in the same class that requires this builder. How to do this?

Also while compile i got the below error

```
The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌─────┐
|  settingsTemplate defined in class path resource [BigtableChannelPrimer .class]
```

Whats wrong with this?

Comment: Why do you want to make this change?  Generally, builders are better for complex objects like this.

Comment: Actually i am trying to implement [this](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigtable/blob/main/google-cloud-bigtable/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigtable/data/v2/stub/BigtableChannelPrimer.java). I added same code, in that i got error in constructor like `Parameter 0 of constructor in ourPackage.BigtableChannelPrimer required a bean of type 'com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2.stub.EnhancedBigtableStubSettings' that could not be found` so i am trying to create a bean and implementing like this

Answer (score 1):

What's the use case of implementing your own `BigtableChanelPrimer`?

If you want to set up channel priming, you could do so with `BigtableDataSettings`:

```
BigtableDataSettings settings = BigtableDataSettings.newBuilder()
BigtableDataSettings.setProjectId(bigtable_project_id)
    .setInstanceId(bigtable_instance_id)
    .setPrimingTableIds(tableIds)
    .setRefreshingChannel(true);

BigtableDataClient client = BigtableDataClient.create(settings.build());
```

You can find the documentation here: https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-bigtable/latest/com/google/cloud/bigtable/data/v2/BigtableDataSettings.Builder.html under `setRefreshingChannel` and `setPrimingTableIds`.